# Update mysql table with data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Is it possible to run an UPDATE command on mysql 5.0 with a sub select.

The command I would like to run is this:

```
UPDATE book_details
SET live = 1 
WHERE ISBN13 = '(SELECT ISBN13 FROM book_details_old WHERE live = 1)';
```

ISBN13 is currently stored as a string.

This should be updating 10k+ rows.

Thanks,

William

Comment: Yes it is possible. The discussion on this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) should help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just a litle change and you got it:

```
UPDATE book_details
SET live = 1 
WHERE ISBN13 in (SELECT ISBN13 FROM book_details_old WHERE live = 1);
```

Comment: The static "1" is not data from another table as requested.

Comment: This won't be very perfomative over large datasets.

Answer (score 190):

```
UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2
SET t1.field_to_change = t2.field_with_data
WHERE t1.field1 = t2.field2;
```

Answer (score 23):

```
UPDATE book_details AS bd, book_details_old AS old
SET bd.live=1  
WHERE bd.isbn13=old.isbn13  
AND old.live=1;
```

Answer (score 6):

To update a table from data in another table:

```
UPDATE table1, table2
SET table1.field1 = table2.field1
WHERE table1.id = table2.id;
```

For example:

```
UPDATE transaction, member
SET transaction.Memberid = member.memberId
WHERE transaction.CardId = member.CardId;
```

Answer (score -3):

To Update data From Other Table

```
UPDATE  tab t1, tab t2
SET     t1.company_name = t2.company_name
WHERE   t1.id = t2.id
```