# Give row in other table same values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to migrate an existing database to another. The problem is as follows:

I have 2 tables :

1.) hhhhhhhhyhhjhjhhhhhh, rows are     :

```
relatie_id,
tempvar
```

2.) op_clienten_communicatie, rows are :

```
Nummer,
Volledige naam,
Volledig adres,
Postcode,
Plaats,
Communicatiemiddel,
Nummer/Adres,
tempvar
```

When i execute the query ;

```
UPDATE op_clienten_communicatie, hhhhhhhhyhhjhjhhhhhh
SET op_clienten_communicatie.Nummer = hhhhhhhhyhhjhjhhhhhh.relatie_id
WHERE op_clienten_communicatie.tempvar = hhhhhhhhyhhjhjhhhhhh.tempvar
```

I only get ALL the `op_clienten_communicatie.Nummer` fields updated with the same (first entry) from `hhhhhhhhyhhjhjhhhhhh.relatie_id`

The result I'm looking for is that all the rows in `op_clienten_communicatie.Nummer` should be updated with the existing values from `hhhhhhhhyhhjhjhhhhhh.relatie_id`.

Comment: Must be a bad day if you name your table `hhhhhhhhyhhjhjhhhhhh`

Comment: You're right, it's created in a frenzy :-)

Comment: before running the update query, are the nummer and relatie_id fields different (side-by-side) when you run the query `select nummer, relatie_id, h.tempvar from op_clienten_communicatie o inner join hhhhhhhhyhhjhjhhhhhh h on o.tempvar = h.tempvar`?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414828/update-mysql-table-with-data-from-another-table), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202075/advanced-mysql-query-update-table-with-info-from-another-table).

Comment: Hi gangreen, Nummer=int(11), relatie_id=int(11)

Answer (score 0):

What is the cardinality of tables `hhhhhhhhyhhjhjhhhhhh` and `op_clienten_communicatie`? is it `one-to-many` or `many-to-many`?

If `one to many`

```
UPDATE op_clienten_communicatie a 
           INNER JOIN hhhhhhhhyhhjhjhhhhhh b
              on a.tempvar = b.tempvar
SET a.Nummer = b.relatie_id
```

But if many-to-many, how would you know which `tempvar` will be joined?

*PS: kindly change the name of the table, kinda sounds weird*