# Error in Mysql query with LIKE %...%

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a table using another table. I am not able to determine how to use LIKE %…% feature here. Please help me out.

Table1:

**TableToBeUpdated:**

```
id | location | value
------------
1  | california | I am going to be here soon.
2  | Nill | Hello I love playing chess and yes.
3  | Nill | my hotel room is just shitty!
4  | Nill | Why on earth God doesn’t live on earth!
5  | Nill | friends of friends and their dogs.
```

Table2:

**TableToCheckFrom :**

```
uniqueid | location | keyword
---------------------
1        | Texas | Why on earth
2        | NewYork   | friends and their
3        |   Washington | love playing chess
4        | NewYork   | their dogs
```

*The result should be:*

```
id | location | value
------------
1  | California | I am going to be here soon.
2  | Washington | Hello I love playing chess and yes.
3  | Nill | my hotel room is just shitty!
4  | Texas | Why on earth God doesn’t live on earth!
5  |NewYork| friends of friends and their dogs.
```

——

I am using this formula but its giving me constant error:

```
UPDATE TableToBeUpdated, TableToCheckFrom
SET TableToBeUpdated.location = TableToCheckFrom.Location
WHERE TableToBeUpdated.Value LIKE %TableToCheckFrom.Keyword%
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `%` in quotes and concatenate them to the keyword. And you need to join the two tables so you can refer to columns from both of them.

```
UPDATE TableToBeUpdated AS u
JOIN TableToCheckFrom AS c ON u.Value LIKE CONCAT('%', c.Keyword, '%')
SET u.location = c.Location
```

Comment: 1. Perfect!! 2.Genious!!  Worked flawlessly! - Thank You!

Comment: what if I want to include this in your query:
WHERE TableToBeUpdated.location IS NOT NULL

Comment: Put that at the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You query is wrong (you never tell the DBM that you want to access the TableToCheckFrom table). 
For an idea on how write such queries look at this question
[Update mysql table with data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414828/update-mysql-table-with-data-from-another-table)

If you find the like %% as an additional difficult strip it: first prepare a working query with a simply condition and then add the like one.