# Updating multiple records in a single query from existing data using the Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, sql-update, laravel-query-builder

I have an inventory system with bins, lots, and transactions.

```
Bin:
  has many lots

Lot:
  belongs to a bin
  belongs to many transactions

transaction_lot (pivot)
  - quantity

Transaction:
  belongs to many lots
```

Right now I have an attribute on `Transaction` that calculates the transaction value using the pivot data:

```php
public function getValueAttribute()
{
   return $this->lots->sum(fn (Lot $lot) => $lot->unit_value * abs($lot->pivot->quantity));
}
```

As a query optimization I want to store this directly on the transaction instead of having to pull the lots each time. I can iterate over all existing transactions, but there's millions of them and I'm hoping to get it done more efficiently. I'm building this logic into a command in case I need to do future maintenance on the tables.

```
transaction_lot:
transaction_id | lot_id | quantity 
1              | 1      | 5
1              | 2      | 3
2              | 2      | 2
3              | 3      | 3

lot:
lot_id | unit_value
1      | 10
2      | 12
3      | 15
```

The end result should be:

```
transaction:
transaction_id | value
1              | 86    // = 5*10 + 3*12
2              | 24    // = 2*12
3              | 45    // = 3*15
```

Can this be done in a single [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) query? I stumbled across [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9636034/4468423) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331882/4468423) but 1) my SQL isn't great, 2) not sure if it's even valid SQL, and 3) the query builder [doesn't seem to support this kind of operation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#running-database-queries) without resorting to raw statements (maybe because of 2?). I want to do something like this but the SUM is giving me issues:

```sql
UPDATE transaction t, transaction_lot tl, lot l
SET t.value = SUM(l.unit_value * ABS(tl.quantity))
WHERE t.transaction_id = tl.transaction_id;
AND tl.lot_id = l.lot_id
```

Alternatively with joins (?):

```sql
UPDATE transaction t
JOIN transaction_lot tl ON tl.transaction_id = t.transaction_id
JOIN lot l on l.lot_id = tl.lot_id
SET t.value = SUM(l.unit_value * ABS(tl.quantity))
WHERE t.transaction_id = tl.transaction_id;
```

Lastly, can this be done using the query builder methods (apart from using `DB::raw()`)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the query builder by joining a subquery containing the calculated transaction values, though not without a few `DB::raw()`s. First create the subquery to calculate the transaction values:

```php
$transaction_lot_values = DB::table('transaction_lot')
    ->join('lot', 'lot.lot_id', '=', 'transaction_lot.lot_id')
    ->select([
        'transaction_lot.transaction_id',
        DB::raw('SUM(lot.unit_value * ABS(transaction_lot.quantity)) as value'),
    ])
    ->groupBy('transaction_lot.transaction_id');
```

Next we can pass this subquery to an update query using [`joinSub`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#subquery-joins):

```php
DB::table('transaction')
    ->joinSub($transaction_lot_values, 'transaction_lot', fn (JoinClause $join) => $join
        ->on('transaction_lot.transaction_id', '=', 'transaction.transaction_id')
    )
    ->update(['transaction.value' => DB::raw('transaction_lot.value')]);
```

Disclosure: An earlier AI-generated answer (since deleted) led me to this solution.

Comment: I have also tested this code to ensure it results in the desired end state.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using sql cases

In Mysql

```
UPDATE db.transactions
SET PRICE = CASE  
          WHEN id = 3 THEN 500
          WHEN id = 4 THEN 300
       END 
WHERE ID IN (3, 4)
```

In Laravel

```
$vat = 0.20;
$transactions = Transaction::get();

$cases = []; 
$ids = [];
$params = [];

foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
 $cases[] = "WHEN {$transaction->id} then ?";
 $params[] = $transaction->profit * $vat;
 $ids[] = $transaction->id;
}

$ids = implode(',', $ids);
$cases = implode(' ', $cases);
if (!empty($ids)) {
  \DB::update("UPDATE transactions SET `price` = CASE `id` {$cases} END WHERE `id` in ({$ids})", $params);
}
```

Comment: This solution is fine if you only have a handful of rows, but doesn't scale very well. Running this with only _dozens_ of rows will produce a very long SQL statement. I shudder to think what the generated CASE statement for _thousands_ or even _millions_ of rows would look like.